# Difference between queryset attribute and get_queryset() method in django?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-class-based-views

I am learning class based views in Django. I was reading the Django documentation and read about queryset attribute and the get_queryset() method. When googled them I came across this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19707855).

I tried to replicate the result using my code:

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'polls/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:2]

class IndexView2(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'polls/index2.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_question_list2'
    queryset = Question.objects.all()
```

In answer it is mentioned that when you set queryset, the queryset is created only once, when you start your server. On the other hand, the get_queryset method is called for every request.

But I was able to insert questions in database and they were available in the page index2.html without restarting, I was able to change the database and changes were reflected on the page index2.html after refreshing the page.

I further googled and found this [link](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/). In the DRF website, it is mentioned that queryset will get evaluated once, and those results will be cached for all subsequent requests.

Can you point where I am going wrong ? What link I am missing ?

Comment: [You will find your answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19707237/use-get-queryset-method-or-set-queryset-variable#:~:text=When%20you%20set%20queryset%20%2C%20the,is%20called%20for%20every%20request.&text=If%20you%20tried%20to%20do,by%20setting%20queryset%20%2C%20then%20date.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `QuerySet` is evaluated once, but the default implementation of `get_queryset`, will use `queryset.all()`, thus each time constructing a new queryset that will force reevaluation.

Indeed, the [implementation of the **`.get_queryset(…)`** method [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.2.x/django/views/generic/list.py#L21-L48) works with:

> ```
> def get_queryset(self):
>     if self.queryset is not None:
>         queryset = self.queryset
>         if isinstance(queryset, QuerySet):
>             queryset = queryset.all()
>     elif self.model is not None:
>         queryset = self.model._default_manager.all()
>     else:
>         raise ImproperlyConfigured(
>             "%(cls)s is missing a QuerySet. Define "
>             "%(cls)s.model, %(cls)s.queryset, or override "
>             "%(cls)s.get_queryset()." % {
>                 'cls': self.__class__.__name__
>             }
>         )
>     ordering = self.get_ordering()
>     if ordering:
>         if isinstance(ordering, str):
>             ordering = (ordering,)
>         queryset = queryset.order_by(*ordering)
>
>     return queryset
> ```

THis thus means that we each time make a new "copy" of the `QuerySet` that will be evaluated. In case the `queryset` is not specified, it will look for the `model` attribute, and work with the `_default_manager` for that model.

If you specified an `ordering` attribute, than that means it will also order the queryset.